# How can I determine which request is periodically timing out through my ssh tunnel?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, mac-osx, linux-networking, ssh-tunnel

I am using a ssh tunnel from OSX combined with the SwitchyOmega chrome plugin to browse via a ubuntu box like this:

```
ssh -D 54321 1.2.3.4
```

This timeout only occurs after I've started chrome. but even after killing chrome it continues to periodically time out every 30 seconds.

```
channel 12: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 8: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 9: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 15: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 10: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 7: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 11: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
```

I'm trying to determine what is causing the timeout and where the request is being sent. any suggestions on how to display more verbose error information for the ssh tunnel?

here is the plugin I am using:
https://github.com/FelisCatus/SwitchyOmega

Answer (score 0):

using the -v option for ssh allowed me to home in on the offending chrome extension.